# Difference between 'anything' and 'X' in Particle Data Group publications' decay modes?

Tags: particle-physics

In the PDG publications, (like [M. Tanabashi et al. (Particle Data Group) Phys. Rev. D 98, 010001 (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.98.030001)
 ) the decay modes of particles are listed.

From the [$B^0$ meson chapter](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/listings/rpp2018-list-B-zero.pdf), I took this screenshot:
[image: Some B^0 Decay Modes]

Whats the difference between $X$ and 'anything'?

Some possibile guesses:

- anything and $X$ are used interchangeably to mean any particle
- anything = any particle, while $X$ is any fermion
- anything = any particle, while $X$ is any hadron (decay mode $\Gamma_2$ has a $X_c$)

I tried searching the original (~2000 page) publication for the word 'anything', but the difference between $X$ and 'anything' doesn't seem to be explained.

Comment: for some reason I cannot access the pdg site so I cannot check for an answer.. tentatively : The "anything" is an inclusive term, as in "crossection for proton proton to anything" is the total crossection.Or "proton proton" to "proton plus anything." It might include part of the decays below, if they have a K+ or K-, in the D decays , but I would have to check the article.

Comment: if you add up the D modes they sum up to the K.. see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/dmeson.html

Comment: I get that it means 'all decay modes that produce either $K^+$ or $K^-$ plus other stuff', but then the question is what kind of 'other stuff' does 'anything' mean, and how is 'anything' different from 'X' ?

Comment: look at the link I gave for D decays, neutrinos and electrons for example.

Comment: file opened. Look at Γ2 It has an X denoting "anything else" (ofcourse consistent with quantum numbers of the B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between "anything" and X.   They are exactly the same.   We (PDG) should fix that.  Thank you.  Michael

Comment: Is there a historical reason for the different naming?

Comment: @knzhou X is used as the symbol for the "unknown/unspecified"  content of "anything, afai remember.

Comment: Alright, thanks.  While I have your ear Michael, there's a spelling mistake and odd sentence around page 190 of Tanabashi 2018: "Where availale the uncertainty the total uncertainty is reported as the statistical and systematic contributions separately and in this order."